# Can't boot Parrotsec anymore, not sure what to do about it

Tags: linux, boot, partition, windows, parrotsec

In attempting to switch to Windows 10 I appear to have tampered with an essential partition. Currently,  parrot loads for a bit and then goes to a black screen filled with cryptsetup errors such as:

- ALERT! encrypted source device UUID=8eb39559-65f7-4dcb-2fb447c98cf4 does not exist, can't unlock sda5_crypt
- waiting for encrypted source device...
  Volume group parrot-vg not found
  Cannot process volume group parrot-vg

I'm pretty sure that it was caused by accidentally formatting a partition (sda5) during the Windows install. Not that the install was going swimmingly before that. Is there anything at all that I can do about this?

Comment: You apparently have an encrypted partition but you do not unlock it during boot - perhaps GRUB options are missing LUKS statements?

Comment: Please do not post images. They may be removed by the hoster and they are not indexable/searchable. Please type relevant lines or errors, configuration or code.

Comment: noted and fixed. is there any way to add the statements?

Comment: Please detail the partition layout, something like `lsblk` (I know you cannot boot it, but perhaps by a live USB Linux?).  Are you using LUKS on LVM? Sounds like it. From a live Linux system you could also do `pvs` and `vgs` and look at the layout. Only with a bit of detail we can try to reconstruct the GRUB commands (are you using GRUB?). It would also be good to see the current GRUB structure ("best of" is sufficient if you are typing it!).

Comment: It should also be noted that it may be faster to install the system again - but then all data would in most install scenarios be lost.